# Android save/restore xml widgets inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

in my application i'm using simple Fragment by some xml widgets such as EditText, after type into EditText and rotate phone EditText content clear and i cant find any helpful document about this problem, i'm try to use this code by dont resolve problem

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putString("contact", uiFiller.edt_waybill_id.getText().toString());
        Log.e("Save: ", edt_waybill_id.getText().toString());
    }
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState!=null) {
            String contact = savedInstanceState.getString("contact");
            Log.e("Restore: ", contact);
            edt_waybill_id.setText(contact);
        }
    }
```

in this code i can save and restore, but i can not setText that into EditText, problem is in rotate phone i have only first created fragment state, if i setText normally into `onCreateView` i can successful restore it, i can not type into EditText and restore after created view

Comment: what else are you doing with your `edt_waybill_id` ? looks like you overriding your values somehow, maybe in `onResume` or `onStart`. The code above should work.

Comment: use `uiFiller.edt_waybill_id.setText(contact)` 
instead of `edt_waybill_id.setText(contact)`

Answer (score 0):

use `uiFiller.edt_waybill_id.setText(contact)` instead of `edt_waybill_id.setText(contact)`

Maybe you are calling `uiFiller.edt_waybill_id.setText(contact)` in `onCreateView()` too?